# Staggering Columns using paracol

Tags: columns, paracol

I am attempting to create "parallel" text that is temporal in nature. For example, the second author wrote the beginning, the first author wrote the second section, the fourth author wrote the third section, the third author wrote the fourth section, the fourth author wrote the fifth section, the first author wrote the sixth section, etc... The text should not align but should allow the reader to move between these sections in order. I have examined the paracol documentation and googled the issue. Apologies if I have misspecified the problem or overlooked a resource. I have included a MWE. TIA.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}
   \centering Introduction     \\
   \raggedright
   This is an introductory paragraph. \\ 
   The document should be able to ``bounce'' back and forth between columns. For example, columns 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, \dots

   \begin{paracol}{4}

      \textbf{This is the second paragraph and should align with the bottom of the first paragraph (second column).}
      \switchcolumn*[1]

      \textbf{This is the first paragraph.}
      \blindtext
      \switchcolumn*[0]

      \textbf{This is the fourth paragraph and should align with the bottom of the third paragraph (fourth column).}
      \blindtext
      \switchcolumn*[3]

      \textbf{This is the third paragraph and should align with the bottom of the second paragraph (first column).}
      \blindtext
      \switchcolumn*[2]

   \end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [`paracol`](https://ctan.org/pkg/paracol) and your code is very close as is.

If you look at the compilation the paragraphs are staggered in separate columns but just jump right one column, rather than to the specified column, and the specified column numbers are actually getting typeset instead.
This is because the intended usage is `\switchcolumn[i]*` (which is arguably unusual for LaTeX syntax).

On top of that `\switchcolumn` needs to come before rather than after (text is typeset immediately, so typeset according to the preceding `\switchcolumn` directive).
After that, text either needs to come in the correct vertical/temporal order or be input (alongside some argument to indicate order) into some macros which can store and sort the paragraphs as necessary.
The former is naturally much easier.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}
   This is an introductory paragraph.
   
   The document should be able to ``bounce'' back and forth between columns. For example, columns 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, \dots
   
   \begin{paracol}{4}
      \switchcolumn[1]*
      \textbf{This is the first paragraph.}
      \blindtext

      \switchcolumn[0]*
      \textbf{This is the second paragraph and should align with the bottom of the first paragraph (second column).}

      \switchcolumn[3]*
      \textbf{This is the third paragraph and should align with the bottom of the second paragraph (first column).}
      \blindtext
      
      \switchcolumn[2]*
      \textbf{This is the fourth paragraph and should align with the bottom of the third paragraph (fourth column).}
      \blindtext
   \end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image: First page of the compiled code showing the first paragraph in the second column, second paragraph in first column, and third paragraph in fourth column]